# How do I access the various items in this NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Say I have NSDictionary *foo below:

```
complete = 1;
    list =     {
        8213812 =         {
            excerpt = "Lorem ipsum dolor...."
        }
        8810100 =         {
            another = "iasjdiasd..."
        ...
```

I know for accessing "complete" I use [response objectForKey:@"complete"] but what about the others?

Comment: Retrieve the inner dictionary, then access it.  Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just keep accessing the keys from the nested dictionaries until you get what you want. For accessing the "list", it is, unsurprisingly

```
[[response objectForKey:@"complete"] objectForKey:@"list"]
```

And for accessing the 8213812-style keys inside list — well, it depends on their type. Assuming they're strings, it would be

```
[[[response objectForKey:@"complete"] objectForKey:@"list"] objectForKey:@"8213812"]
```

or, to use the newer, more succinct syntax

```
response[@"complete"][@"list"][@"8213812"]
```

But they might be NSNumbers or something else, and in case case you would use the appropriate NSNumber.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[[response objectForKey:@"list"] objectForKey:@"8213812"] objectForKey:@"excerpt"]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
NSDictionary *list = [response objectForKey:@"list"];
NSDictionary *inner = [list objectForKey:@"8213812"];
NSString *excerpt = [inner objectForKey:@"excerpt"];
```

Or, alternatively:

```
NSString *excerpt = response[@"list"][@"8213812"][@"excerpt"];
```

etc..